# CSS div length is too big

Tags: css, html

How can I make a CSS div which width is as tall as the text it contains? I tried

```
div.reqspace {
  float : left;
  width : 10px;
}
```

but found that there is no length attribute. Now my div is almost as wide as the screen is.

```
   <?php include("sitestartend.php");
   site_start('xyz);?>
   <?php include("helpfun.php");
   $addr = getRealIpAddr();
   if ($addr != '$myaddr') {
   echo '<p>Sivusto on kehitteillä.</p></body></html>';
   die();
   }
   include("navbar.php"); ?>
   navbar ladattu!
<div id="reqspace">
Sähköpostiosoite: <br/>
Valitse salasanasi: <br/>
</div>
<input type="text" name="email" value="" />
<input type="text" name="email" value="" />
<input type="password" name="password" value="" />
<input type="submit"/>
</body>
</html>
```

sitestartend.php

```
<?php
function site_start($name) {
   echo '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">';
   echo '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">';
   echo '<head>';
   echo '  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>';
   echo '  <title>'.$name.'</title>';
   echo '  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />';
   echo '</head>';
   echo '<body>';
}

function site_end() {
   echo '</body>\n</html>';
}
```

helpfun.php

```
<?php
function getRealIpAddr() {
  if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
  {
    $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
  }
  elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
  {
    $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
  }
  else
  {
    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  }
  return $ip;
 }
?>
```

Comment: By "width is a tall" do you mean the height and width are the same?

Comment: Width isn't tall.  Are you looking for height?  Post more of your code, if you can.

Comment: Points of clarification: Width = horizontal, Height = vertical, length is not really meaningful in CSS to my knowledge.

Comment: I mean that the div should contain two lines of text and its width is the same as longer of the text. Height should by two text lines.

Comment: is your text dynamic , if so you can add a tooltip or cut some letters after it crosses certain length , you can have ... after some text. I have a function to do that , let me know if you want.

Comment: @jaska , please provide more info or create sample on jsfiddle , we can easliy fix the problem

Comment: @gov: I would like to have two boxes: e-mail and password. User can give them but at the moment they aren't aligned properly.

Comment: Got it! <div id="reqspace"> should be replaced by <div class="reqspace">.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a `height` value, in px.  Also, in a floated div, it's often helpful to use something like this:

```
<div class="reqspace">My content
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

That "clear" div, while empty, will help the browser understand where the bottom of the div is.  It's not the cleanest HTML ever, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for the height attribute?  Although you are setting things in terms of pixels so it'll really only be as wide and tall as the text as long as it doesn't exceed that.  Might try a fluid measurement like em.

Answer (score 0):

you must do that:

```
div.reqspace {
  position : relative;
  width : auto;
  display : table;
}
```

for example, if you have a list with x number of child li, in this way you list li will be with dynamic width on each child.

Comment: every browser, except ie6, need a fix for it. Can you copy paste your html please?